# Vagrant - how to have host platform specific provisioning steps

Tags: ruby, vagrant

We've got a diverse dev team, one on Windows, another on Ubuntu and another on OSX. Being windows boy, I setup the first version of the vagrant setup script which works fabulously ;)

However, when running it on the Ubuntu host, the first time it gets to a provision step that calls a bash script, it fails due to permissions.

On windows, this doesn't matter as the samba share automatically has sufficient permissions to run the bash script (which resides within the project hierarchy, so is present in the /vagrant share on the VM), but with ubuntu I need to set the permissions on this file in the provision script before I call it.

This isn't the problem and to be honest I suspect even with the extra "chmod" step it would still work fine under windows, but, is there a way in the vagrant file to flag certain provisioning steps as 'Windows Only', 'Linux Only' or 'Mac Only'?

i.e. in pseduo code, something like.

```
.
.
if (host == windows) then
  config.vm.provision : shell, : inline => "/vagrant/provisioning/only_run_this_on_windows.sh"
else if (host == linux) then
  config.vm.provision : shell, : inline => "/vagrant/provisioning/only_run_this_on_linux.sh"
else if (host == osx) then
  config.vm.provision : shell, : inline => "/vagrant/provisioning/only_run_this_on_osx.sh"
end if
.
.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone just upset (possibly his question/answer was down voted) and went into "down vote spree" -- seen it one my 3 most recent answers.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Find out current OS inside Vagrantfile.

Add this into your Vagrantfile:

```
module OS
    def OS.windows?
        (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
    end

    def OS.mac?
        (/darwin/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
    end

    def OS.unix?
        !OS.windows?
    end

    def OS.linux?
        OS.unix? and not OS.mac?
    end
end
```

Then you can use it as you like.

```
if OS.windows? [then]
    code...
end
```

Edit: was missing the ? on if condition.

Example used to test:

```
is_windows_host = "#{OS.windows?}"
puts "is_windows_host: #{OS.windows?}"
if OS.windows?
    puts "Vagrant launched from windows."
elsif OS.mac?
    puts "Vagrant launched from mac."
elsif OS.unix?
    puts "Vagrant launched from unix."
elsif OS.linux?
    puts "Vagrant launched from linux."
else
    puts "Vagrant launched from unknown platform."
end
```

Execute:

```
# Ran provision to call Vagrantfile.
$ vagrant provision
is_windows_host: false
Vagrant launched from mac.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've got an error now and my Ruby skills aren't good at all :(

"Vagrantfile:145:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `unix' for OS:Module (NoMethodError)"

Vagrant File:
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

I put the module code immediately below 'VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"' and then the if just before the 'end' at the bottom of the file.

if OS.unix
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo chmod 755 /vagrant/provision/*.sh";
  end

(sorry for the pants formatting...)

Comment: I fixed it, I removed the '?'s from the code given and it works fine. :) If you can amend your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: This is the most useful vagrant conditional / platform / environment tutorial I could find !

Comment: Put the linux check before the unix one or linux will never be seen as such.

Answer (score 65):

Note that Vagrant itself, in [the Vagrant::Util::Platform class](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb) already implements a more advanced version of the platform checking logic in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26889312) by [BernardoSilva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150700/bernardosilva).

So in a Vagrantfile, you can simply use the following:

```
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows? then
    myHomeDir = ENV["USERPROFILE"]
else
    myHomeDir = "~"
end
```

Comment: This is more like "if platform is windows, apply monkeypatch here". Love it.

Comment: Note you can also use `Vagrant::Util::Platform::mac?` and I don't think that `then` should be there.

Comment: The [`then` is optional in Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression), which is the language Vagrantfile is written in.

Comment: To check if your machine is a Mac, the code is actually `Vagrant::Util::Platform::darwin?`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version using the Vagrant utils that checks for mac and windows:

```rb
    if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
        # is windows
    elsif Vagrant::Util::Platform.darwin?
        # is mac
    else
        # is linux or some other OS
    end
```

Comment: not sure why not, but this failed for me on mac, with both `Vagrant::Util::Platform.mac?` and `Vagrant::Util::Platform::darwin?` . Bernado Silva answer worked great.

Comment: There is a typo mistake above. Replace `elseif` by `elsif` and all works fine

Answer (score 0):

When I read the original question according to me it is not how to find out on which OS vagrant it self runs, but which OS do the virtual machines to be provisioned have. That is why you want to run a different provision script depending on the diffent OSses of the new VMs, eg: "/vagrant/provisioning/only_run_this_on_${OS_OF_NEW_VM}.sh".

Unfortunately Vagrant does not have this capability (yet), so this is my solution: I define my VMs on top of my vagrant file:

```
   cluster = {
  "control.ansible.RHEL76" => { :ip => "192.168.1.31", :type => 0, :cpus => 1, :mem => 1024, :box_image => "centos/7" },
  "app01.ansible.RHEL76"   => { :ip => "192.168.1.32", :type => 1, :cpus => 1, :mem => 1024, :box_image => "centos/7" },
  "app02.ansible.RHEL76"   => { :ip => "192.168.1.33", :type => 1, :cpus => 1, :mem => 1024, :box_image => "centos/7" },
  "winserver"          => { :ip => "192.168.1.34", :type => 2, :cpus => 1, :mem => 1024, :box_image => "mwrock/Windows2016" },
}
```

Then these conditions in my code can provision different ways depending on the OS of the VM's:

```
if "#{info[:box_image]}" == "mwrock/Windows2016" then
  puts "is_windows_host: #{info[:box_image]}"
  config.vm.provision : shell, inline => "/vagrant/provisioning/only_run_this_on_windows.psl"
end
if "#{info[:box_image]}" == "centos/7" then
  puts "is_linux_host: #{info[:box_image]}"
  config.vm.provision : shell, inline => "/vagrant/provisioning/only_run_this_on_linux.sh"
end
```

By the way, only the ansible controller should have ansible installed, because in real life (yes the office) I do not use vagrant but an ansible controller, which I also want in my lab (OK Virtual Box on both my Windows 10 desktop as well as my Ubuntu laptop). I use a condition to test "type = 0" (which I use for a ansible "controller"). Only the ansible controller starts ansible_local to provision the cluster of VMs with ansible.

```
   if info[:type]  == 0 then
     cfg.vm.provision "shell", inline: "if [ `which ansible` ] ; then echo \"ansible available\"; else sudo  yum -y update; sudo yum -y install epel-release; sudo yum -y install ansible; fi"
     cfg.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
        ansible.extra_vars = { ansible_ssh_user: 'vagrant' }
        ansible.inventory_path = "./production"
        ansible.playbook = "rhelhosts.yml"
        ansible.limit = "local"
     end # ansible_local
```

This is displayed during a vagrant provision:

PS D:\Documents\vagrant\top> vagrant provision control.top.RHEL76
is_linux_host: centos/7
is_linux_host: centos/7
is_linux_host: centos/7
is_windows_host: mwrock/Windows2016

This is displayed during a vagrant provision:

`PS D:\Documents\vagrant\ansible> vagrant provision control.ansible.RHEL76`

`is_linux_host: centos/7`

`is_linux_host: centos/7`

`is_linux_host: centos/7`

`is_windows_host: mwrock/Windows2016`

`--- many more lines, not relevant ---`

Have fun experimenting and deploying your multimachine / multi OS labs!